# "module object not callable" with Waitress

Tags: python, heroku, flask, server, waitress

I am trying to deploy my app on Heroku. I have to use Windows, and gunicorn won't work. I tried waitress, which keeps giving me a "module not callable" error whenever I try to load any page.

Note: I haven't deployed it on web so far, was trying `heroku local` before creating a publicly accessible one. It works on `localhost` when using PyCharm.

organization of files

```
/myapp
     requirements.txt
     Procfile
     /myapp
         /static
         /templates
         __init__.py
```

`__init __.py`:

```
# encoding=utf-8
import click

from myapp.application import create_app
from myapp.application import db, login_manager

app = create_app()

from myapp.config import SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS
from myapp.models import User
from myapp.views import *

app.add_url_rule('/home', HomePage.endpoint, 
      view_func=HomePage.as_view(HomePage.endpoint), methods=['GET','POST'])
# pages are defined in views.py

#other code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set debug to false when moving to production
    app.run()
```

`Procfile`:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=5000 myapp:application
```

traceback:

```
\myapp>heroku local
[WARN] No ENV file found
14:58:51 web.1   |  ERROR:waitress:Exception when serving /home
14:58:51 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
14:58:51 web.1   |    File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py",
line 338, in service
14:58:51 web.1   |      task.service()
14:58:51 web.1   |    File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", lin
e 169, in service
14:58:51 web.1   |      self.execute()
14:58:51 web.1   |    File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", lin
e 399, in execute
14:58:51 web.1   |      app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_re
sponse)
14:58:51 web.1   |  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
14:58:51 web.1   |  ERROR:waitress:Exception when serving /favicon.ico
14:58:51 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
14:58:51 web.1   |    File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py",
line 338, in service
14:58:51 web.1   |      task.service()
14:58:51 web.1   |    File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", lin
e 169, in service
14:58:51 web.1   |      self.execute()
14:58:51 web.1   |    File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", lin
e 399, in execute
14:58:51 web.1   |      app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_re
sponse)
14:58:51 web.1   |  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Procfile`, try changing

```
web: waitress-serve --port=5000 myapp:application
```

to

```
web: waitress-serve --port=5000 myapp:app
```

The last argument to [`waitress-serve`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/runner.html#invocation) is `MODULE:OBJECT`, where `OBJECT` is the application object in `MODULE`. Here, you've named your application `app`:

```
app = create_app()
```

(You're not showing us all of your code, but it looks like `myapp.application` is in fact a module, not an object. You import `create_app`, `db`, and `login_manager` from it in your sample code.)

Comment: Am I right to say that the OBJECT can be a factory method also?

Comment: @variable, "factory method" is a bit loaded, but [if this lines up](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/runner.html#invocation) you should add the `--call` flag: "A number of frameworks, _web.py_ being an example, have factory methods on their application objects that return usable WSGI functions when called. For cases like these, `waitress-serve` has the `--call` flag. Thus: `waitress-serve --call myapp.mymodule.app.wsgi_factory` would load the `myapp.mymodule` module, and call `app.wsgi_factory` to get a WSGI application function to be passed to `waitress.server`".

Answer (score 0):

Waitress has it's own `app`, so you need to distinguish your `app` correctly. @Chris's answer shows you how to do so via `Procfile`. Here's another way, for those using Flask:

**app/**init**.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="some path", static_folder="another path")
```

**main.py**

```
from waitress import serve
from app import app as my_app  # renamed to distinguish from waitress' 'app'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(my_app, host="localhost", port=5005)
```

This allows you to keep your app named `app` in a routes file, since that is isolated from waitress

**app/routes.py**:

```
@app.route('/dothing1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def dothing1():
  pass
```